# Spring Authorization server OIDC logout not working after refreshing token in Spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to logout from spring cloud gateway and spring authorization server after access token has been refreshed but I am getting below error in authorization server.

*org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Request Parameter: id_token_hint*

Logout works fine, if I logout before token gets refreshed first time.

I found that spring cloud gateway is sending first id token for logout which doesn't exist in the db after token got refreshed.

How this issue can be fixed?

Spring cloud gateway security config is as below

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
   private final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

   @Inject
   public SecurityConfig(final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
       this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
   }

   @Bean
   public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisDefaultTemplate(final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
       final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();

       template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
       template.setKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
       return template;
   }

   @Bean
   @Primary
   public SessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository(final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
       return new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(redisTemplate);
   }

   @Bean
   public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http, @Value("${web.origin}") String webOrigin) {
       // @formatter:off
       return http
           .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource(webOrigin)))     
           .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
           .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
               .pathMatchers("/api/*/public/**", "/api/public/**", "/logout").permitAll()
               .anyExchange().authenticated())
           .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
               .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler(webOrigin + "/login.html")))
           .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
           .logout(logout -> logout
               .logoutUrl("/logout")
               .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(webOrigin)))
           .build();
       // @formatter:on
   }

   @Bean
   @Primary 
   public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
       ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
       ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

       ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
           ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
               .authorizationCode()
               .refreshToken()
               .clientCredentials()
               .build();

       DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
           new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
               clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
       authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

       return authorizedClientManager;
   }

   private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(final String webOrigin) {
       final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
       final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

       configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
       configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(webOrigin, "null"));
       configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
       return source;
   }

   private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(final String webOrigin) {
       final OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);

       logoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(webOrigin);
       return logoutSuccessHandler;
   } 
}
```

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8085/login/oauth2/code/gateway
            client-id: app-bff
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - phone
              - email
            provider: spring
            client-name: app-bff
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth2/token
            jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth2/jwks
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
  data:
    redis:
      host: redis-11759.c262.com
      port: 11759
      username: default
      password: ******
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: api
          uri: http://localhost:8080/api/**
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
          filters:
            - SaveSession
            - TokenRelay=
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie           

        - id: auth
          uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/**
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
          filters:
            - SaveSession
            - TokenRelay=
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie



web:
  origin: http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: I think this might be worth submitting an issue on the [spring-security issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new/choose).